# How do you get silver and gold scales in Salmon Run?

Tags: splatoon-3

When you face the King Salmonoid in Salmon Run, you always receive scales, whether you win or lose.  But it seems completely random how it works - sometimes I win and I get all bronze scales, and sometimes I lose and get a gold scale.

How does this system work?  How do I get more silver and gold scales?

Answer (score 5):

The number of scales you get is independent from  the chance of getting silver and gold scales.  You get 2 scales just for encountering the boss, then +1 scale for each 12.5% health you take off his health bar (up to 8 for a full kill).  The you get +1 scale for each 10 seconds you have left on the timer up to +3, for an absolute maximum of 13 scales.

The rarity of each scale is directly proportional to the hazard level.  At 0% hazard level, you have a chance of 5% silver scale and 0% of gold.  These increase by 0.045% and 0.009% respectively per hazard level percent, for a maximum of ~18.5% of silver and ~2.7% of gold at 300% hazard level.  You can calculate your chances of getting scales based on your hazard level using [this calculator](https://leanny.github.io/splat3/coop.html).

[Source](https://twitter.com/LeanYoshi/status/1578133396794007552)

Comment: with the amount of scales things cost.... this is gonna be a really long grind.

Comment: Yeah its definitely been balanced that you will play SR for a LONG TIME.